# Hanging interface in heavy processing scripts

Tags: org-babel

Emacs org-babel is an excellent notebook tool for exploratory and interactive statistics in ESS. Now, I need to run very heavy  scripts in R and the entire interface of emacs hungs for the duration of the code execution. This is an important limitation of babel.

- Are there ways of avoiding this?

Here is a MWE:

```r
#+begin_src R :results output

library(umx)
data(docData)

var1 = paste0("varA", 1:3)
var2 = paste0("varB", 1:3)

tmp = umx_scale_wide_twin_data(varsToScale= c(var1, var2), sep= "_T", data= docData)

mzData = subset(docData, zygosity %in% c("MZFF", "MZMM"))
dzData = subset(docData, zygosity %in% c("DZFF", "DZMM"))

m1 = umxDoCp(var1, var2, mzData= mzData, dzData= dzData, sep = "_T",
             causal= TRUE, autoRun = F)

umxSummary(m1)
#+end_src
```

Update: I already tried ob-async, but it is not compatible with : session, which reduces babel usefulnes.

Comment: Clarify what you mean by "hung". If it's just a slowdown, or Emacs is legitimately waiting for something, then your question might make sense here. But if the Emacs process is really hung, that's similar to a crash, and you should report it using `M-x report-emacs-bug`. And please specify your Emacs version: `M-x emacs-version`.

Comment: Maybe [ob-async](https://github.com/astahlman/ob-async) can help?

Comment: https://github.com/jackkamm/ob-session-async seems to be what you are looking for, but he says that the functionality is already in upstream Org mode.

Comment: @NickD this looks promising, let me test

Comment: Sometimes Emacs waits for a babel block to finish, sometimes it doesn't. I'm not sure why. If it freezes while you're waiting for the cose to finish, C-g sometimes enables you to continue editing without stopping the calculation. Since you're running in a session, you can see for yourself if execution has stopped after you try this.

Comment: Omg, the C-g trick did it for me! @Tyler could you answer this question, so I can accept! The :async results precisely in the same results, I think it is the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Emacs is waiting for an orgmode cose block to run, you can regain control with 'C-g'. I'm not sure why this works, but so far I haven't had the cose block stop running when I do this.